# How to start multiple domains at once in glassfish?

Tags: glassfish

The command to open a particular glassfish domain is

```
./asadmin start-domain domain_name
```

Say, I want to start domain1, domain2, domain3 all at once, how'd I do it?

If it's not possible, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could ues && operator

```
./asadmin start-domain domain1 && ./asadmin start-domain domain1 && ./asadmin start-domain domain1
```